# Set Azure to not precompile source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms, continuous-deployment

I have a **webforms** application and **Azure** as continues deployment environment. **Kudu** (built in Azure deployment tool) seems that **tries to compile** my webforms application and fails every time with message in Azure terminal:

> The site directory path should be the same as repository root or a sub-directory of it.

I googled it and found that Azure tries to compile app. So **I want to tell Azure to not do it. Question is - how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted this issue out suddenly! Just **removed .sln file from source code**. Pushed it and it works like a charm!